# How to get firstlineno for wraped function with __code__ in python?

Tags: python, inspect, python-importlib

I want to get the co_firstlineno for function in static way, The unwrapped function is ok,
But if a method is wrapped, I can only get the lineno  where the wrapper function  is located.

md.py

```
import functools

def run(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def warper(*args, **kwargs):
        res = func()
        return res
    return warper

def func_unwrapper():
    pass

@run
def func_with_wrapper():
    pass
```

run.py

```
from importlib import util as module_util
import inspect

def load_moudle_by_path(path):
    foo = module_util.spec_from_file_location('md', path)
    md = module_util.module_from_spec(foo)
    foo.loader.exec_module(md)
    return md

def get_line():
    md = load_moudle_by_path('md.py')
    for name, o in inspect.getmembers(md):
        if inspect.isfunction(o):
            print('[{}]{}'.format(name, o.__code__.co_firstlineno))

get_line()


>>>
[func_unwrapper]10
[func_with_wrapper]4
[run]3
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you were hoping for, but the behaviour is expected behaviour.

`func_with_wrapper` really is running the code at line 4, with the code at line 13 (which is what you were probably hoping for / expecting) only being called based on the `func` parameter passed (the `func_with_wrapper` argument).

After your own research, finding `.__wrapped__`, which `functools` graciously adds, there's no need to add something similar yourself.

Your original code will work, if you update:

```
def get_line():
    md = load_module_by_path('md.py')
    for name, o in inspect.getmembers(md):
        if inspect.isfunction(o):
            try:
                if o.__wrapped__:
                    print('decorated [{}]{}'.format(name, o.__wrapped__.__code__.co_firstlineno))
            except AttributeError:
                print('undecorated [{}]{}'.format(name, o.__code__.co_firstlineno))
```

Output:

```
undecorated [func_unwrapper]10
decorated [func_with_wrapper]13
undecorated [run]3
```

Comment: Oh! It's work fine. I found  the update_wrapper() in functools.py that it saved the original func with "wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped"，But I can't access in inspect.getmembers(md), prompting：'function' object has no attribute'__wrapped__'

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and advice.